# Is there any posiiblity to add meta slider code in dynamic side bar for using slider in sidebar

Tags: wordpress, slider

i have custom created dynamic side bar for attached in content page and i want to use meta slider in this widget part but there is error to play slider only showing short code in page

how i resove my problem

how to use slider in widgets

Comment: would you share how did you tried... ??

Comment: i want to use slider in content page and i have already 2 dynamic sidebar and i want to use third dynamic sidebar in bottom to show slider in bottom of page content , can i use slider in sidebar if yes then tell me how i can try for that?

Comment: i think there is no one help me there as per this question ..so sad ?

Answer (score 0):

Use following filter to support shortcodes in widgets.

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

You can place above code in functions.php of your theme.